# Cannot insert data using tableadapter.insert method due to an Auto-Increment field

Tags: c#, database

I need your help since I cannot locate an answer anywhere on the web for my problem.

I'm using C# and I have a table called "People" and I want to use an TableAdapter to add/delete to/form that table. I'm using an sdf file as my database as a "Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 (.NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0)" Data Source.

my code looks like this:

***peopleTableAdapter.Insert(0, byte.Parse(cbAddType.SelectedIndex.ToString()), txtAddName.Text, txtAddCompany.Text, txtAddPhone.Text,
                    txtAddMobile.Text, txtAddEmail.Text, txtAddAddress.Text, txtAddNotes.Text);
peopleTableAdapter.Update(this.hisabati_DBDataSet.People);***

the table contains a field called "ID" which is an auto-increment field with the following

attributes:
 Allow Nulls: No
 Unique: Yes
 PK: No

the first param in the Insert method is asking for the ID, and if I don't enter a value, I'll get a compile error that a value is needed. If I enter a value (as I'm entering 0 above) I get the following error:
Err Msg: Cannot modify that column
Err HRESULT: -2147467259

I know how to insert using Command.ExecuteNonQuery method, but I'm trying to use the TableAdapters throughout my application as it looks like a more elegant way to write and maintain the codde...Any Advice?
Thanks much

Comment: Can you set the ID column as the PK and set autoincrement? then leave it out of your insert statement?

Comment: Is this a designer generated `TableAdapter`?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys.

I posted this question 2 years ago. I ended up throwing away SQL Server Compact Edition and using Firebird. This and many other problems disappeared.

I do not recommend SQL Server Compact Edition to anyone. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the InsertCommand and UpdateCommand of the table adapter. Remove the Auto-Increment column name and values from the set part of those commands.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using that method specifically, create a new row via your People Dataset, then use the TableAdapter to update from that.